# Combining rows into one row, choosing highest score

Tags: r

I have a large dataset with multiple instances of 'Player', and I want to collapse their tournament scores into a single row but keep the row with the highest earnings. It's a large data set so I can't exactly paste the whole thing but a small example table looks like this:

| Player | Earned | T1. | T2 | T3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | 2100 | 5 | N/A | N/A |
| John Doe | 1900 | N/A | 12 | N/A |
| John Doe | 500 | N/A | N/A | 16 |

I'd like to eliminate the N/A values and the duplicate rows by combining Tournament 1, 2, 3 into a single row, and also keeping the highest earnings value (2100), so that it looks more like this:

| Player | Earned | T1. | T2 | T3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | 2100 | 5 | 12 | 16 |

So far I've used top_n(1, Earned) to keep the row with the highest earnings, but it only keeps the score of Tournament1, and I need to fill in the other columns with their scores.

Comment: Are those columns really strings? `"N/A"` is not `NA`.

Comment: No they're just null values actually

Comment: To be clear, R has `NULL`, which those are not, and R has `NA`, which is what most databases and some other languages think of as "null". I'll infer the latter, though my address addresses strings as well.

Comment: Welcome to SO, with regard to @r2evans comments it may be best if you post that part of your data set in a reproducible way using `dput()`(or `dput(head())` if the data set is large) and add it to the question. That way people can check the data by themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your reference to `top_n`, I'm inferring `dplyr` and related packages.

1. If your columns are *strings* (since `"N/A"` is not `NA`), then

   ```r
   func <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE, na = c("NA", "N/A")) {
     if (is.numeric(x)) max(x, na.rm = na.rm) else head(na.omit(setdiff(x, na)), 1)
   }
   library(dplyr)
   dat %>%
     group_by(Player) %>%
     summarize(across(everything(), func))
   # # A tibble: 1 x 5
   #   Player   Earned T1.   T2    T3   
   #   <chr>     <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
   # 1 John Doe   2100 5     12    16
   ```
2. If your columns are `numeric`, though, then we can simplify that to

   ```r
   dat %>%
     # an interim line to change your strings to numbers
     mutate(across(-Player, ~ suppressWarnings(as.numeric(.)))) %>%
     # pick up from here
     group_by(Player) %>%
     summarize(across(everything(), ~ max(., na.rm = TRUE)))
   # # A tibble: 1 x 5
   #   Player   Earned   T1.    T2    T3
   #   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
   # 1 John Doe   2100     5    12    16
   ```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(Player = c("John Doe", "John Doe", "John Doe"), Earned = c(2100L, 1900L, 500L), T1. = c("5", "N/A", "N/A" ), T2 = c("N/A", "12", "N/A"), T3 = c("N/A", "N/A", "16")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not think of any other way to get rid of those `N/A` values and since you were trying to collapse scores into a single row, I guessed they might be numeric values. Hence I changed them into `numeric` type:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(Player) %>%
  mutate(Earned = cummax(Earned),
         across(T1:T3, suppressWarnings(as.numeric))) %>%
  group_by(Player, Earned) %>%
  summarise(across(T1:T3, ~ na.omit(.x)))

# A tibble: 1 x 5
  Player   Max_Earned    T1    T2    T3
  <chr>         <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 John Doe       2100     5    12    16
```

I used reproducible data shared by dear @r2evans, so I would like to thank him for that.
(P.S = I changed the `T1.` to `T1` before using it.

Comment: Good one my friend!!

Comment: Not very satisfied with that! I think I just complicated things a little here as it reminded me of a very challenging problem of late.

Comment: But therefore it is good one. To keep it simple is important but it requires mastering complex trains of thought.

Comment: Exactly, I think as time goes by, I will learn to keep it simpler and more optimized.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to the top presented solution could be with `lead` and `slice`

```
dat %>% 
  arrange(desc(Earned)) %>% 
  mutate(T2 = lead(T2),
         T3 = lead(T3,2)) %>% 
  slice(which.max(Earned))
```

Output:

```
    Player Earned T1. T2 T3
1 John Doe   2100   5 12 16
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` option

```
> setDT(dat)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) max(x, na.rm = TRUE)), Player]
     Player Earned T1. T2 T3
1: John Doe   2100   5 12 16
```